# Sroll indicator on one section of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, scroll, indicator

Can anyone explain how to build scroll indicator for a section in React. I want to have a vertical line that starts filling up when user scrolls to the specific section and to fill to 100% when user scrolls to the end of the section.

I need scroll indicatior in only one section

Answer (score 0):

You could look into framermotion for the animation. They have a very detailed example of how you can achieve what you want.

https://www.framer.com/motion/scroll-animations/

IF you do not want to include a entire library to animate one section, you could try with just javascript, but it will be quite complex.

You could try to get the scroll position inside the container with:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      // scroll handlers here }
    };
    containerName.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);
```

You will need to track container height, scroll position inside the container height and calculate the scroll percentage inside the container and update the value using useState.

Comment: I tried but for some reason it doesnt work. im trying to set the minHeight on my div using scrollYProgress from useScroll hook